# Provide an Explanation or Offer an Explanation?

Tags: word-choice

I know that offer an explanation is more frequent. But I think I have heard Provide an explanation in some cases. I want to know where to use offer and where to use provide.

For example:

> He didn't ...... an explanation for his behaviour.
>
> He .........ed an explanation for the math problem.

I think I heard offer for the first one and provide for the second one. But what is the exact distinction between this two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can both *provide* and *offer* an explanation. You can also *give* an explanation. Which verb to use is up to you. But *provide* sounds a little bit more formal to me than the other 2 verbs I have mentioned.

Comment: I see the first sentence in a 4 choice test and it has provide and offer as different choices. The other two didn't make any sense and I don't remember them. The book's answer was offer. I thought there must be a difference between these two. So both of the answers are right and there is no big difference between these two?

Comment: Both are right. The Oxford Learner's Dictionary says the same. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/explanation